# Linux Mint - unable to boot from Live USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, linux-mint

I made a multi boot usb using Xboot. I've added Linux Mint and some Windows PE's. Bootloader is using syslinux.

Usb drive boots, menu appears, with Windows iso's there is no issue. But at Linux Mint, I started to have bootloop. I see a message repeatedly like

I see these:

```
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sdc: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sdd: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sde: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sdf: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
```

Each line repeats 2 times

In previous versions of Linux Mint there wasn't such issue. I've experienced with 19 and 20 version.

Comment: Change bootloader to Grub4dos and try ; if issue still persistents attach grub4dos configuration file.

Comment: Alternatively try - http://multibootusb.org/page_download/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47076/how-do-i-fix-cant-open-dev-sr0-no-medium-found-on-usb-boot) solution posted on Ask Ubuntu?

Also [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=246748) from the Linux Mint forums.

Comment: Yes I did. I did this way:

After seing welcome screen of Linux Mint: I press tab and change command line into this:

>/casper/vmlinux boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz live-media-path=/casper/ quiet splash ignore_uuid --

Comment: I see these:

/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sdc: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sdd: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sde: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sdf: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found

Each line repeats 2 times

Comment: Another thing, Knoppix works with no issue, Linux Mint and Kubuntu has the same situation.